# Ionic Show Alert not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement the basic ionic popup. I followed this link http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/

When I try to implement I'm getting the following error.

> Cannot read property 'alert' of undefined

Here is my code.

App Module

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services','ngFileUpload'])
```

Controller

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', '$http', function($scope, fileUpload, $http, $ionicPopup, $timeout){
    $scope.showPopup = function() {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'Dont eat that!',
          template: 'It might taste good'
        });
        alertPopup.then(function(res) {
          console.log('Thank you for not eating my delicious ice cream cone');
        });
      };

}]);
```

In my controller, i have some other functionalities like file upload and posting to server etc., I removed that block and submitted only the code related to popup.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Try `['$scope', 'fileUpload', '$http', '$ionicPopup', '$timeout', function($scope, fileUpload, $http, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the inject definition `'$ionicPopup', '$timeout'`

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', '$http', function($scope, fileUpload, $http, $ionicPopup, $timeout){
```

should be

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', '$http', '$ionicPopup', '$timeout', function($scope, fileUpload, $http, $ionicPopup, $timeout){
```

hope this helps.